# Set a different image for each page than the image on another page

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, frontend

I created a project in react and in my files there are several css files for example loginPage.css, tradingPage.css,
app.css...
If I put a background image for the body, it changes on all pages and I try to be more specific, but I can't do it on the entire height of the page, for example I tried to create a div that would wrap the entire page and then set a background image for it, and still it didn't work, the background image was just The div is not the entire length of the page,
Does anyone have an idea how to do this more specifically.
Thanks to all who answer :).

LoginPage.jsx file:

```
 <div className="login-form-container">
       
      <h2>{isSignIn ? 'Sign In' : 'Sign Up'}</h2>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <label htmlFor="email">Email:</label>
        <input
          type="email"
          id="email"
          value={email}
          onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
          required
        />

        <label htmlFor="password">Password:</label>
        <input
          type="password"
          id="password"
          value={password}
          onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
          required
        />

        <br /><button type="submit">{isSignIn ? 'Sign In' : 'Sign Up'}</button>
      </form>

      <p>
        {isSignIn ? "Don't have an account? " : 'Already have an account? '}
        <button type="button" onClick={() => setIsSignIn(!isSignIn)}>
          {isSignIn ? 'Sign Up' : 'Sign In'}
        </button>
      </p>
    </div>
  );
}
```

css file :

```
.login-form-container {
  background-image: url('https://a.c-dn.net/c/content/dam/igcom-websites/sv_SE/images/brochure-                    pages/hero-images/2023/08/18/Trade_Analytics_promotion_HP_Banner_1440px_x720px.png');
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    margin-top: 200px;
    margin-left: 40px;
    padding: 20px;
   
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

For starters, you need to set the `display` property of your `.login-form-container` class in order for it work properly. You can set it to `grid`, `flex` or `block` depending on what your needs are which may look like this

```
.login-form-container{
    /* your other code */
    display: grid;
}
```

Next, you have the `height` of your element set to `500px` which will stop it from being the full height of a screen larger than 500px.  So you could fix that by applying a `min-height` property to your class like this

```
.login-form-container{
    display: grid;
    min-height: 100vh;
}
```

The `100vh` means 100% of the viewport's height so the div will be at least that height or taller.

You also might want to position your background image and decide on how you want it to fill the `div` which can be done with the `background-position` and `background-size` properties. Seeing that you want the photo to be a background you may want to position it to `center` and set the size to `cover` like this

```
.login-form-container{
    display: grid;
    min-height: 100vh;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

What this will do is center the image in the div and make it crop the overflow on all sides.  I hope this helps, if not, make a stackblitz demo with your code and I'll tinker with it to get the results you want, it's hard to tell exactly what you're going for just looking at the code here.